# C# Selenium test case reliability with .Net Core 3 and Blazor

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, blazor

Apologies if this is a long question, it's causing us confusion and is stopping us progressing with a project.

The company I work at had a successful working automated test pack using Page Object Models with C# Selenium, for one of our products.

The product in question **was** coded with .Net Framework.

The product has since been moved to .Net Core 3 with Blazor. The test itself is also being written in .Net Core 3

Even with a re-write this has resulted in the test pack becoming incredibly unreliable.

For example, a test to update a user's personal details updates the text boxes, saves it, asserts that the changes have been made and puts the data back to the previous values.

These are using straight forward methods and will only run reliably the first time.

A second run will fail to press the update button.

The third run will fail to clear the text boxes (even with a clear command). It places the new data in the text box at the end of the existing data. On one text box if fails to do anything.

The puzzling thing is that the tests will report as passing on the 1st and 2nd runs.

Example methods I've written that are as follows:

```
public void InputProfile(string PersonalEmail, string MobilePhone, string VehicleReg)
{
  //update personal email
  Page.Profile.PersonalEmail.Click();
  Page.Profile.PersonalEmail.Clear();
  Page.Profile.PersonalEmail.SendKeys(PersonalEmail);

  //update mobile phone
  Page.Profile.MobilePhone.Click();
  Page.Profile.MobilePhone.Clear();
  Page.Profile.MobilePhone.SendKeys(MobilePhone);

  //update vehicle registration 
  Page.Profile.VehicleRegistration.Click();
  Page.Profile.VehicleRegistration.Clear();
  Page.Profile.VehicleRegistration.SendKeys(VehicleReg);
}

public void UpdateProfile()
{
  //pressing the update button go back to the main page
  Page.Profile.UpdateButton.Click();
  Hooks.WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://XXXX/");
  Hooks.Wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("ContactLink")));
}

public void AssertProfile(string PersonalEmail, string MobilePhone, string VehicleReg)
{
  //Get the current text from the boxes
  string AssertEmail = Page.Profile.PersonalEmail.GetAttribute("value").ToString();
  string AssertMobile = Page.Profile.MobilePhone.GetAttribute("value").ToString();
  string AssertVehicleReg = Page.Profile.VehicleRegistration.GetAttribute("value").ToString();

  //Check the text with the expected values
  Assert.AreEqual(PersonalEmail, AssertEmail);
  Assert.AreEqual(MobilePhone, AssertMobile);
  Assert.AreEqual(VehicleReg, AssertVehicleReg);
}
```

We're using the following list of Nuget packages, I suspect something's wrong here. With the exception of the DotNetSeliniumExtras.PageObjects.Core they're the same as we've used in the .Net Framework version of the test.

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- Selenium.WebDriver
- Selenium.Support
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver
- Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver
- Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver
- DotNetSeliniumExtras.WaitHelper
- DotNetSeliniumExtras.PageObjects.Core
- NUnit
- NUnit3TestAdapter

Comment: Did you update your dependencies to latest versions ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. We've updated all the Nuget packages we're using. We started a completely fresh project.

Comment: Have you tried running in incognito mode?As to make sure not cookies and cache is store?

Comment: Hi Marwaha, thanks for the response. 
Currently, we're running the test on IE (we have permission issues in our environment that prevent us from running it on Chrome). 
In IEDriver I have set up the option: 
EnsureCleanSession = true 
Is this what you mean or is there some other option I need to set?

Comment: Do you close and re-launch the browser every time, or are you re-using the same browser window for each test?